Unable to get result using Contains query to Search service/ AzureOpenAI using python code
I am trying to get search results using Python code from Azure OpenAI, and the query works as expected when using a single track. However, when I attempt to modify the query from using eq to contains, I encounter an error. I'm trying to implement a search that allows multiple tracks within a single query, but I'm unable to retrieve results. Below is my working query.
def search_knowledgebase(search_query, track=None):
    with tracer.span(name='search_knowledgebase'):
        vector = Vector(value=generate_embeddings(search_query),
                        k=3, fields='embedding')
        print('search query: ', search_query)
        text_content = ''

        if track == 'Voice':
            track = 'OV'

        filter_condition = "track eq '" + track + "'" if track not in (None, 'All') else None


        # Search KBs
        with tracer.span(name='search_kb'):
            results = search_client.search(
                search_text=search_query,
                vectors=[vector],
                select=['id', 'title', 'content', 'track', 'keywords'],
                query_type='semantic', 
                query_language='en-us',
                semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
                query_caption='extractive',
                query_answer='extractive',
                facets=['track'],
                filter=filter_condition,
                top=3
            )

            kb_found = False
            if results:
                for result in results:
                    if result['@search.reranker_score'] >= 2:
                        if not kb_found:
                            text_content += 'KB Results:\n'
                            kb_found = True
                        text_content += f'Score:{result['@search.reranker_score']}<a href="' \
                            f'{kb_base_url}{result['id']}{kb_url_suffix}">' \
                            f'{result['title']}</a>' \
                            f'\nKeywords: {result['keywords']}\n' \
                            f'\n{result['content']}\n'

        if track != 'Consumer':
                results = wiki_search_client.search(
                    search_text=search_query,
                    vectors= [vector],
                    select=['path', 'filename', 'content'],
                    query_type='semantic',
                    query_language='en-us',
                    semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
                    query_caption='extractive',
                    query_answer='extractive|count-3',
                    top=3
                )

                wiki_found = False
                if results:
                    for result in results:
                        if result['@search.reranker_score'] >= 2:
                            if not wiki_found:
                                text_content += 'Wiki Results:\n'
                                kb_found = True
                            page_path = get_page_path(result['path'], result['filename'])
                            text_content += f'Score: {result['@search.reranker_score']}<a href="' \
                                f'{wiki_base_url}{page_path}">' \
                                f'{result['filename']}</a>\n{summarize(result['content'])}\n'

        if not text_content:
            text_content = 'No KB or Wiki results found.'

        print('text_content', text_content)
        return text_content

The code has been modified, but I'm unable to retrieve results from OpenAI.
def search_knowledgebase(search_query, track=None):
    with tracer.span(name='search_knowledgebase'):
        vector = Vector(value=generate_embeddings(search_query),
                        k=3, fields='embedding')
        print('search query: ', search_query)
        text_content = ''

        if track == 'Voice':
            track = 'OV'

        if track not in (None, 'All'):
            track_list = track.split(',')
            filter_condition = " or ".join([f"contains(track, '{t.strip()}')" for t in track_list])
        else:
            filter_condition = None


        # Search KBs
        with tracer.span(name='search_kb'):
            results = search_client.search(
                search_text=search_query,
                vectors=[vector],
                select=['id', 'title', 'content', 'track', 'keywords'],
                query_type='semantic', 
                query_language='en-us',
                semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
                query_caption='extractive',
                query_answer='extractive',
                facets=['track'],
                filter=filter_condition,
                top=3
            )

            kb_found = False
            if results:
                for result in results:
                    if result['@search.reranker_score'] >= 2:
                        if not kb_found:
                            text_content += 'KB Results:\n'
                            kb_found = True
                        text_content += f'Score:{result['@search.reranker_score']}<a href="' \
                            f'{kb_base_url}{result['id']}{kb_url_suffix}">' \
                            f'{result['title']}</a>' \
                            f'\nKeywords: {result['keywords']}\n' \
                            f'\n{result['content']}\n'

        if track != 'Consumer':
                results = wiki_search_client.search(
                    search_text=search_query,
                    vectors= [vector],
                    select=['path', 'filename', 'content'],
                    query_type='semantic',
                    query_language='en-us',
                    semantic_configuration_name='my-semantic-config',
                    query_caption='extractive',
                    query_answer='extractive|count-3',
                    top=3
                )

                wiki_found = False
                if results:
                    for result in results:
                        if result['@search.reranker_score'] >= 2:
                            if not wiki_found:
                                text_content += 'Wiki Results:\n'
                                kb_found = True
                            page_path = get_page_path(result['path'], result['filename'])
                            text_content += f'Score: {result['@search.reranker_score']}<a href="' \
                                f'{wiki_base_url}{page_path}">' \
                                f'{result['filename']}</a>\n{summarize(result['content'])}\n'

        if not text_content:
            text_content = 'No KB or Wiki results found.'

        print('text_content', text_content)
        return text_content

Below is the exact piece of code I am trying to midify
From
filter_condition = "track eq '" + track + "'" if track not in (None, 'All') else None

To
if track not in (None, 'All'):
            track_list = track.split(',')
            filter_condition = " or ".join([f"contains(track, '{t.strip()}')" for t in track_list])
        else:
            filter_condition = None


test the filter condition separately in portal to check whether it is working or not.

You can use the search.in function in filter which matches a field against a delimited list of strings.
This is much faster than the explicit comparing the field against the strings using eq and or.
Below is the code
filter_condition  =  f"search.in(track, '{track}' , ',')"  if  track  not  in (None, 'All') else  None

Sample output:
"search.in(track, 'test,race,one' , ',')"

Here, you need to pass the string and delimiter where it splits and search against each string.
This is faster and simplified version of below filter condition.
(track eq 'test' or track eq 'race' or track eq 'one')

If you want to make full-text search along with filter expression then
you go with search.ismatch and search.ismatchscoring  functions.
